# I'm trying to search through db and count all data items under specific column name

Tags: sql, oracle, count, case

I'm trying to do a count of data items under the column name 'TXN'

Trying to search through all the tables in the database

I have tried:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM all_tab_columns WHERE OWNER='RGSWKF_PRGM' where COLUMN_NAME like '%TXN%';
```

But I get the error:

```
ORA-00904: "COLUMN_NAME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

After seraching online for other ways, I came accross setting a case:

```
SELECT COUNT (case when COLUMN_NAME like '%TXN%') FROM all_tab_columns WHERE OWNER='RGSWKF_PRGM';
```

But I'm getting:

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
```

Would you know where I'm going wrong on the above statements? Or am I approaching this completeley wrong?

Fairly new to SQL, I'm trying to browse through the oracle data dictionary but not finding anything.

Comment: For your first query, replace the second WHERE with an AND.

Comment: For your second query change COUNT to SUM and add THEN 1 END after '%TXN%' and before the closing bracket.

Comment: @RichardHansell its bring back a result but it seems way to small so logically there is something wrong. If I try to just search for the items under that column name in one table like:

SELECT SUM (case when COLUMN_NAME like '%TXN%' THEN 1 END) FROM field_selection_rule; 

I get:

ORA-00904: "COLUMN_NAME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: ORA-00904 indicates that COLUMN_NAME doesn't exist in the table called field_selection_rule.  I can't comment on the result being "too small" as the logic seems sound for that first query?

Answer (score 1):

In the first query you have two WHERE keywords. Replace the second WHERE with AND:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM all_tab_columns
    WHERE owner='RGSWKF_PRGM' AND column_name LIKE '%TXN%';
```